# "Experts say they are concerned" - sentence breakdown

Tags: grammar, subject-complement

I am trying to deconstruct the following sentence:

> Experts say they are concerned

- Experts = subject
- say = verb
- they are concerned = object

Experts say what? gives you the object: they are concerned

Now, let's breakdown the object:

> they are concerned

- they = subject
- are = verb
- concerned  = subject complement or the predicate nominative

Is this a correct breakdown of the sentence above (Experts say they are concerned)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good to me. There might be fancy terms for the subject/verb/object that make up the object of the main verb "say," but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: "they are concerned" must be an object clause. Since clauses have a subject (they), and a verb (are) and this does. There is also an object (concerned), so this must be an independent clause as well: because "They are concerned" can stand alone as a sentence.